# Trying to understand NavigationController retain count for ViewControllers on its stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, release

I have an UITableViewController as the rootViewController for my navigatorController.
When I press a table cell I do the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {
MessageHistory *msg = (MessageHistory *)[[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
ConversationViewController *chatController = [[ConversationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ConversationView" bundle:nil andUser:msg.user];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chatController animated:YES];
[chatController release];
```

But when I'm returning from the chatController (using the back button on the navbar) I get  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

commenting

```
//[chatController release];
```

solves the problem. How? I thought when pushing to the navigationController adds a retain count and when pop from it release it?
Also I believe if I'm not including the release after pushing to the navcontroller I'm generating  a leak.
Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: This looks like you're addressing deallocated instance somewhere. Run your app with NSZombieEnabled set to see what instance you have problems with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know about NSZombieEnabled it helped as you said to find the deallocated instance.
For those like me who didn't know about NSZombieEnabled here is how to enable it in xcode:
1. Double-click an executable in the Executables group of your Xcode project.
2. Click the Arguments tab.
3. In the “Variables to be set in the environment:” section, make a variable called “NSZombieEnabled” and set its value to “YES”.
Ensure to remove this for distribution!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem a few times, and almost went crazy trying to find the error.

In my case, I had a UIWebView in my second view with the UIViewController set as it's delegate. In my UIViewController dealloc method, I forgot to put webView.delegate = nil.

When the second UIViewController was popped and thus deallocated, the UIWebView was sending a message to it's delegate (the second UIViewController, which didn't exist anymore).

Don't know if this applies to you, but I spend days searching for this error, so perhaps it is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing although it was not my problem (see my comment to Vladimir's), yours is a scenario I will probably reach on my project too. Nice to keep it in mind